# Get list of tables used in a complex query

Tags: oracle

Suppose there is an oracle query which calls an function

```
select * from table(xyz(to_date('10/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')))
```

and function xyz has two select statements in it

```
 select * from A
```

and

```
select * from B
```

So this query references(reads/writes/updates) two tables `A` and `B`

Is there a way to know the number of tables that are  referenced when I run this query on oracle ?

Comment: I don't see any way for this unless you have a look at code of function xyz.

Comment: There is one for SQL.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then you can always query `{ dba | all | user }_dependencies` data dictionary view to get that information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you tell if a PL/SQL Package, Procedure, or Function is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670164/how-can-you-tell-if-a-pl-sql-package-procedure-or-function-is-being-used)

Comment: Not a duplicate question. My Question is different. I want to extract the list of tables in each query.